# FadeIn one element and fadeOut all others

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to fadeIn one element with jQuery and when click on another element fadeOut that element. I know how to fadeIn the divs but how do i fadeout all others?
thanks for the help!

the divs have the ids `#id1 #id2 #id3 #id4`

here´s my Jquery

```
function trying(id){

var fade_in =function (e){
        $(id).fadeIn();
    };
    $(id).click(fade_in);
};

trying("#id1");
trying("#id2");
trying("#id3");
trying("#id4");
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML. It's best to use DOM traversal to find the sibling/child/parent elements related to the one which raised the event, instead of providing all the ids

Comment: Use classes, and fade out on the class not the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy said, you should give these elements a class. Let's call the class potato, because who doesn't love potatoes.

```
$potatoes = $('.potatoes');

$potatoes.click( function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('fast'); // fade in the div that was clicked
    $potatoes.not( $(this) ).fadeOut('fast'); // fade out every other div
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me a lot of headaches trying to work out why my code wasn't working!

Answer (score 0):

How about this (assuming that these elements are `div`):

```
$('div[id*=id]').click(function(){//when any div whose id contains 'id'

     $('div[id*=id]').not($(this)).hide();
     //hide all divs whose id contains 'id' except the current `div` clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sold on using javascript to provide the visual effect of what you're trying to do; however, I would use javascript–in this case jquery-to apply class states to the elements. Let me know if this example helps, http://output.jsbin.com/kuxefunibi/.

All that I am doing is applying a `.active` class to the wrapper and then applying a `.current` class to the currently clicked on block. With that, anytime the `.active` is present, all of the `.blocks` inside of it are semi-transparent unless there is a `.current` class applied to the `.block` class. Then and only then will that particular `.block.current` will be solid.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.block').on('click', function() {
    $(this)
      .siblings().removeClass('current').end()
      .addClass('current')
      .parent().addClass('active');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block-list.active .block {
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  opacity: 0.25;
}
.block-list.active .current {
  opacity: 1;
}
.block {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333333;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="block-list">
    <div class="block block-1">some text here</div>
    <div class="block block-2">some text here</div>
    <div class="block block-3">some text here</div>
    <div class="block block-4">some text here</div>
    <div class="block block-5">some text here</div>
    <div class="block block-6">some text here</div>
    <div class="block block-7">some text here</div>
    <div class="block block-8">some text here</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant? [jsfiddle fadein fadeoutall](http://jsfiddle.net/2w2f2/438/) I added some comments too.

Here is the js code:

```
$('div[id*="id"]').click(function() {
    $('div[id*="id"]').fadeOut('normal');//not recommended but if you don't want to use a class, then this will fadeOut all elmts that have ids starting with 'id'
    $(this).fadeIn('normal');//fadeIn clicked jQuery object
});
```